# Setting Response.StatusCode using MvcContrib.TestHelpher

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-testhelper

I've got a very simple test method, using MvcContrib.TestBuilder to setup the controller (and mock the HttpContext etc...)

```
    [Test]
    public void http404_returns_status_code_of_404()
    {
        var builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
        controller = new ErrorController();

        builder.InitializeController(controller);

        var result = controller.Http404();

        Assert.That(controller.Response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(404));
    }
```

My implementation looks as simple as:

```
    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;

        return View();
    }
```

However, my test is always failing, because `Response.StatusCode` is always 0

Even if I debug, and evaluate `Response.StatusCode` after `Response.StatusCode = 404;`
 it is still 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpResponse instance is a mock. So you should assert it like this:

```
controller.Response.AssertWasCalled(x => x.StatusCode = 404);
```

instead of:

```
Assert.That(controller.Response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(404));
```

But instead of setting some status codes in my controller action I would simply return the proper `ActionResult`:

```
public ActionResult Http404()
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

and test it like this:

```
// arrange
var builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
var sut = new ErrorController();
builder.InitializeController(sut);

// act
var actual = controller.Http404();

// assert
actual.AssertResultIs<HttpNotFoundResult>();
```

Looks more readable IMHO.